# Trying to enter a name in a textbox, hit ok, and have that form close and pass the info to another forms label

Tags: vb.net

***THE CODE FROM THE FIRST WINDOW GOES INTO A TEXT BOX AND YOU HIT THE BUTTON HERE.

```
 Private Sub btnOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

***THE CODE ON THE FORM WHERE I WANT THE INFO TO BE PLACED IS HERE.

```
 Private Sub Loan1Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.lblCompanyName.Text = DataEntryForm.txtCompanyNameInput.Text
End Sub
```

Anyway's that's what I found on a youtube video and im having trouble getting it to work. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: so where is thew code to "pass" the info from Frm1 to Frm2?  That has to happen before you close Frm1.  If that little snippet in the second block is supposed to be it, it is in the wrong place and getting the info at the wrong time.

Comment: Yah I could be doing it wrong.  I watched a few youtube video's and was trying implement their techniques and i'm struggling. This is my reference http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbSdHau8STc

Comment: let THIS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/ be your reference!

Comment: I do sometimes but I like watching live demonstration which youtube makes it clear for a newbie like to me to see whats going on. :)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the data to an instance of the form:

```
Private Sub btnOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
   Dim f As New OtherForm
   f.lblCompanyName.Text = txtCompanyNameInput.Text
   f.Show()
   Me.Close() 'make sure this form is not the one that closes the app if it closes
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ill try to mess around with that.  :)